# Conditional header's content depending on xsim solutions being printed or not

Tags: koma-script, xsim

Is there a way to set the header contents depend on whether  the solutions are printed or not ?

```
\documentclass[headsepline]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xsim}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}


 \cohead{Solutions are not printed}

%\xsimsetup{solution/print}
%\cohead{Solutions are printed}


\begin{document}
\begin{exercise}
body of exercise \theexercise
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
solution of the  exercise number \theexercise
\end{solution}

\begin{exercise}
body of exercise \theexercise
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
solution of the  exercise number \theexercise
\end{solution}

\begin{exercise}
body of exercise \theexercise
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
solution of the  exercise number \theexercise
\end{solution}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a new `\if` flag, `\ifprintsolutions` (default `false`).  By declaring `\printsolutionstrue`, the header gets changed along with the solutions being printed.

```
\newif\ifprintsolutions
\printsolutionstrue% COMMENT THIS LINE OR NOT

\documentclass[headsepline]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xsim}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\ifprintsolutions
  \xsimsetup{solution/print}
  \cohead{Solutions are printed}
\else
 \cohead{Solutions are not printed}
\fi

\begin{document}
\begin{exercise}
body of exercise \theexercise
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
solution of the  exercise number \theexercise
\end{solution}

\begin{exercise}
body of exercise \theexercise
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
solution of the  exercise number \theexercise
\end{solution}

\begin{exercise}
body of exercise \theexercise
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
solution of the  exercise number \theexercise
\end{solution}
\end{document}
```